# How to register NCommon with StruceMap?

Tags: structuremap, ncommon

IM using NCommon with NHibernate and would like to use StruceMap as my IOC. Doesnt anyone know how to register NCommon with StructureMap?

Here is the info on NCommon.

https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/

Here is how its done with Castle Windsor

```
    foreach (var type in types)
            container.Register(Component.For<IController>().ImplementedBy(type)
                                        .LifeStyle.Transient
                                        .Named(type.Name.Replace("Controller", "")));

        var containerAdapter = new NCommon.ContainerAdapter.CastleWindsor.WindsorContainerAdapter(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
containter.Configure(c => {
  foreach (var type in types)
    c.For<IController>()
     .Use(type)
     .Named(type.Name.Replace("Controller", ""));
});

var containerAdapter = new NCommon.ContainerAdapter.StructureMap.StructureMapContainerAdapter(container);
```